# Extra comment lines in designer code-behind for custom component

Tags: .net, code-behind, windows-forms-designer

I created a component in .NET and in the designer code-behind, there are three extra comment lines for the component after it is dragged+dropped onto a form. A normal MS component appears like this:

```
///
/// myComponentClass1
///
//properties for the component set in the designer here
```

but mine appears like this:

```
///
/// myComponentClass1
///
///
///
///
//properties for the component set in the designer here
```

Any ideas on how to stop Visual Studio from adding those extra comment lines?

Comment: Does it _really_ matter?

Comment: @ChrisBint - if user ask the question - yes it does matter